# How is the word format for MIPS lui instruction?

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm a baby in MISP and I'm confused with this.
My question is very simple, **lui** is a I-type instruction in MISP:

```
+------+------+------+--------------------+
|opcode|  rs  |  st  |    16bits offset   |
+------+------+------+--------------------+
```

So, where goes the destination register? in **rs** or **rt**? Or am I wrong?

Comment: This is clearly specified in the [MIPS32 Architecture For Programmers Volume II](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3410/2013sp/MIPS_Vol2.pdf).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the `lui` instruction, `rs` is ignored (it's usually left as zero); `st` is the destination.

Comment: Can you clarify? From what I see on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_instruction_set#MIPS_assembly_language) the syntax for the lui instruction appears to completely omit rs although there is a space in the actual binary (since it is an I-type instruction).

Comment: The assembler syntax doesn't provide anything that maps to the `rs` field, as it's not meaningful. The bits still exist in the instruction encoding, though.

Comment: Is `lui` the only example has such property?